# How to use Spring Data JPA to search for a non unique index?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm learning about Spring Data JPA with Spring Security with user roles and I want to know how to use Spring Data JPA to search for a non unique index. For example I have 3 MySQL tables and this is the join table:

[image]

And I want to find all roles for a specific user. So I want to search in the user_role table by user_id and this isn't a unique key.

User entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class AppUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

}
```

Role Entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="role")
public class AppRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="role_id")
    private long id;

    private String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

User_Role Entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="user_role")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private AppUser appUser;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
    private AppRole appRole;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public AppUser getAppUser() {
        return appUser;
    }

    public void setAppUser(AppUser appUser) {
        this.appUser = appUser;
    }

    public AppRole getAppRole() {
        return appRole;
    }

    public void setAppRole(AppRole appRole) {
        this.appRole = appRole;
    }
}
```

I want to create the UserDetails for Spring Security because I want to use user roles. And I need to find all roles for a specific user. I've created repositories interfaces that extends JpaRepository but I don't know how to search for user_id. Can I use Spring Data JPA to search for this user_id? Something like userRoleRepository.findByUserId(user.getId). Any feedback will be apreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like ther's something wrong with your entities, you don't need a `UserRole` entity, even though you need a join table.

JPA allows you to do that with `@ManyToMany` and `@JoinTable` annotation :

```
pubic class User {
  ...
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name="USER_ROLE")
  private List<Role> roles;
  ...
}
```

That way, you can easily fetch your user first using your user Repository, then the roles associated to it.

```
User user = userRepository.findOne(userId);
List<Role> roles = user.getRoles();
```

Comment: Thak you Matt, I know how to do it in this way using @ManytoMany, but I want to do it in another way, and I've found this tutorial here: https://o7planning.org/en/11705/create-a-login-application-with-spring-boot-spring-security-jpa , I see that he use JPA and I want to know if it possible to do it with Spring Data Jpa